# android httpget string url exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 40

Tags: android, http-get, illegalargumentexception

there is problem to read content of url page
when i call this url :

```
http://holiday-tricot.com/HOL_And/insert​Comment.php?id=13&comment=mycomment&name=myname
```

and my codes:

[My Code](http://ideone.com/OIj9TW)

when i call this page, it shows me 0 or 1 to accept comment

And Errors:

> 08-27 16:40:06.471: E/LogError(16625): Exception :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index
>   40:
>   http://holiday-tricot.com/HOL_And/insert​Comment.php?id=13&comment=mycomment&name=myname
>   08-27 16:40:06.471: W/System.err(16625):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index
>   40:
>   http://holiday-tricot.com/HOL_And/insert​Comment.php?id=13&comment=mycomment&name=myname
>   08-27 16:40:06.478: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.478: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.(HttpGet.java:75)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.486: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.connectWS(Webservice_InsertComments.java:138)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.486: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.doInBackground(Webservice_InsertComments.java:77)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.486: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.doInBackground(Webservice_InsertComments.java:1)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.494: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.494: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.494: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.494: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.494: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.502: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.502: W/System.err(16625):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>
> 08-27 16:40:06.502: E/LogError(16625): Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index
>   40:
>   http://holiday-tricot.com/HOL_And/insert​Comment.php?id=13&comment=mycomment&name=myname

So

> Webservice_InsertComments.java:138

is: Line 31 In My Codes

How I Can't Fix It?

### Thank You.

removed zero-width space
so it shows me other error:

> 08-27 17:23:24.307: I/LogInfo(19976): url After Replace >>
>   http://holiday-tricot.com/HOL_And/insertComment.php?id=13&comment=hhhhhh&name=hhhhhh 08-27 17:23:25.822: E/LogError(19976): Exception :
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException 08-27 17:23:25.822:
>   W/System.err(19976): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>   08-27 17:23:25.830: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
>   08-27 17:23:25.830: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   08-27 17:23:25.830: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   08-27 17:23:25.838: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.connectWS(Webservice_InsertComments.java:137)
>   08-27 17:23:25.838: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.doInBackground(Webservice_InsertComments.java:74)
>   08-27 17:23:25.838: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   webservice.Webservice_InsertComments.doInBackground(Webservice_InsertComments.java:1)
>   08-27 17:23:25.846: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264) 08-27 17:23:25.846:
>   W/System.err(19976):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   08-27 17:23:25.846: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 08-27
>   17:23:25.853: W/System.err(19976):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 08-27
>   17:23:25.853: W/System.err(19976):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   08-27 17:23:25.861: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   08-27 17:23:25.861: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 08-27 17:23:25.869:
>   W/System.err(19976): Caused by:
>   org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to
>   'http://holiday-tricot.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33'
>   08-27 17:23:25.877: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectHandler.java:173)
>   08-27 17:23:25.877: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:923)
>   08-27 17:23:25.877: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:475)
>   08-27 17:23:25.877: W/System.err(19976):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   08-27 17:23:25.885: W/System.err(19976):  ... 12 more 08-27
>   17:23:25.885: E/LogError(19976): Exception:
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Answer (score 1):

There's a [zero-width space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) just before the `C` in your URL `insertComment.php`. Remove it.

Comment: How To Do It? Replace With Witch One Of ASCII Characters?

Comment: Use backspace/delete on your keyboard.